# How to properly align this text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

for visual reference please click on this image: https://i.gyazo.com/d17f94a4cf87dfb555780717773f49b3.jpg

I am trying to get the text shown in the picture to be right next to its respective picture, they are all "h2" elements. Both the img and h2 elements are stored inside of an un-ordered list. The html looks roughly like this with some basic resizing CSS:

```
#container{
    margin:auto;
    width:70%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding:10px;
}
img{
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
h2{
    text-align: right;
}


<nav>
  <div id ="container">
    <ul id = "list">
         img1
         title1
         img2
         title2
    </ul>
 </div>
```

To reiterate, how can I get the titles to be to the side of the images. Also, is it possible to put a different colored background to distinguish between two separate images in the list and alternate between something like light gray and blue?

Comment: could you add the css code as well ?

Comment: Put the text in your HTML *before* the respective image, and set the text to `float: right;`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<nav>
  <div id ="container">
    <ul id = "list">
         <li><img src="https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/trump.jpg"/></li>
         <li><h2>title1</h2></li>
         <li><img src="https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/trump.jpg"/></li>
         <li><h2>title2</h2></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

img{
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}
h2{
    text-align: right;
    margin:0px;
}
#list{
     list-style:none;
}
li{
    width:48%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frmmh6mh/

Although I would recommend using a table or floating divs for this purpose instead of a ul.

Also, there should be only one h2 tag on a page, use h3 instead. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML labels, this way the image and text will always be paired together. For example,

```html
<div id="container">
  <label for="picture1"><!--Put text here!--></label>
  <img src="<!--img1-->" id="picture1" align="left"/>
  <label for="picture2"><!--Put text here!--></label>
  <img src="<!--img2-->" id="picture2" align="left"/>
</div>
```

The labels will then be tied to whatever has `id="picture1"` or `id="picture2"`. The `align="left"`'s tell the picture to be to the left of their labels.